# Copy image from internal php script

Tags: php, image, copy

I need to get a image saved on a mysql DB to a folder into the server...

I have the script: `watch_pic.php` the which get the byte of the image and prints it into a based64 code, I send the Header and the image can be seen on browser, then if I write on the browser 'watch_pic.php?id=1234' it will display and image. I need to copy these image to a folder in the server with any name... I think that using the 'copy' function I could get the image, but it don't works. I can do it using CURL, but I don't  wanna like to use this, cause i haven't install it on the server, and could be conflictive with other extras... How can I caopy the image without using CURL??

Answer (score 0):

If you included the code of watch_pic I could give you the exact code to make it work (and if you put it up I can certainly improve this answer). However I can give you a suggestion:
somewhere in that file there will most likely be a line like this:

```
imagejpeg($img);
```

(or imagepng or imagegif)

and just change that to something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["save"]) {
    imagejpeg($img,$_GET["save"]);
    }
else {
    imagejpeg($img);
    }
```

and call it by `image_pic.php?id=####&save=filepathandnametosaveto.jpg`

HTH;

Nick